# XSL variable assignment

Tags: xslt

I have another simple xsl variable question.  I'm trying to evaluate an expression and toggle an 'AM' or 'PM' suffix.  The variable never evaluates to anything.  I've even changed my test to  with no luck.

```
<xsl:variable name="DisplayAMPM">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(substring($LastBootUpTime, 9,2))>11">
      <xsl:value-of select="PM"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="AM"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="DisplayAMPM"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `value-of`, put the "AM" and "PM" in quotes so that the processor sees it as a string.

Also, if you reference the variable, like you're trying to do in the `copy-of`, don't forget the `$`.

```
<xsl:variable name="DisplayAMPM">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(substring($LastBootUpTime, 9,2))>11">
      <xsl:value-of select="'PM'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="'AM'"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$DisplayAMPM"/>
```

Comment: thanks, the single quotes around the AM\PM (along with the $ in var name) worked.

Comment: Elaboration: without the quotes, you're asking for the value of child elements named `AM` or `PM`. The result is an empty nodeset, and the string value of an empty nodeset is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a runaway `>` character in your `test` attribute which should of course be `&gt;`. 
Secondly, you don't copy your variable (`$DisplayAMPM`), instead you copy the (nonexistent?) `DisplayAMPM` element child node set.

Comment: I made the suggested changes, still no luck.  The test looks like  <xsl:when test="1=1"> and the copy-to <xsl:copy-of select="($DisplayAMPM)"/>